# Why is the relay switched by a NPN transistor still on while the Arduino out is off (low)?

Tags: arduino, transistors, digital-logic, relay

I have a circuit as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkjbI0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Note:**

In the above schematic some pins of Arduino Nano are not shown for simplicity purposes. Also, SW1 and SW2 are not switches but sensors as shown below:

[image]

Here is the arduino code:

```
//include LCD library
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

//Initialize an LCD object
/*Pins should be mentioned in this order:
  Reset
  Enable
  Data4
  Data5
  Data6
  Data7
*/
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2);
int upSensor = 11;
int downSensor = 10;
int continuousSwitch = 8;
int suddenSwitch = 9;

unsigned long counter = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(upSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(downSensor, INPUT);
  pinMode(continuousSwitch, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(suddenSwitch, OUTPUT);

  //Begin the LCD interface
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  lcd.print("MOTOR OFF");
}

void loop()
{

  if(counter == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(suddenSwitch, HIGH);
    delay(1000); //1 Second
    digitalWrite(suddenSwitch, LOW);
  }

  Serial.println("upSensor: " + String(digitalRead(upSensor)));
  Serial.println("downSensor: " + String(digitalRead(downSensor)));

  if(digitalRead(upSensor) == HIGH && digitalRead(downSensor) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(continuousSwitch, HIGH);
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("ON");
    counter++;
  }

  if((digitalRead(upSensor) == LOW && digitalRead(downSensor) == LOW))
  {
    digitalWrite(continuousSwitch, LOW);
    lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
    lcd.print("OFF");
    counter = 0;
  }

}
```

Everything is working fine except relay RLY2.

No matter if switch sw1 and sw2 are open or close, RLY2 is always ON. I mean RLY2's COMMON connection is always connected to NORMALLY OPEN Connection. If I measure the output from pin D9 of arduino, then I can see that it is changing according to the state of the switches SW1 and SW2. But the Relay RLY2 is always ON. WHY????

**Update:**

Before removing transistor:

I have added a diode between emitter and ground. Also changed the resistor R2 from 1K to 470E.

Voltages of Q2:

A. When D9 is HIGH:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 6.15V
Emitter - Ground ------> 0.70V
Base - Ground ---------> 1.40V

Collector - Base ----> 4.75V
Collector - Emitter -> 5.40V
Base - Emitter ------> 0.70V
```

B. When D9 is LOW:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 7.90V
Emitter - Ground ------> 0.70V
Base - Ground ---------> 0.65V

Collector - Base ----> 7.25V
Collector - Emitter -> 7.20V
Base - Emitter ------> 0.50V
```

I will remove the transistor, after Trevor checks above voltages and makes sure if transistor is sick.

**Update2:**

After removing transistor:

Voltages of Q2:

A. When D9 is HIGH:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 15.06V
Emitter - Ground ------>  0.15V
Base - Ground --------->  4.03V

Collector - Base ----> 12 V
Collector - Emitter -> 15.6V
Base - Emitter ------> 3.70V
```

B. When D9 is LOW:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 16.90V
Emitter - Ground ------> 0.12V
Base - Ground ---------> 0 V

Collector - Base ----> 16.8V
Collector - Emitter -> 16.4V
Base - Emitter ------> 0.15V
```

I have also measured the transistor:

```
Base - Collector    --> 647
Base - Emitter      --> 642
Collector - Emitter --> 1
Collector - Base    --> 1
Emitter - Base      --> 1
Emitter - Collector --> 1
```

So, from above mentioned readings, I think the transistor is OK. Am I right?

**Update3:**

I have put new 2N2222 after removing the first one:

Voltages of Q2:

A. When D9 is HIGH:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 0.76V
Emitter - Ground ------> 0.74V
Base - Ground ---------> 1.52V

Collector - Base ----> 0.74 V
Collector - Emitter -> 0.02V
Base - Emitter ------> 0.77V
```

B. When D9 is LOW:

```
Collector - Ground ----> 10.25V
Emitter - Ground ------> 0.70V
Base - Ground ---------> 0.73V

Collector - Base ----> 9.50V
Collector - Emitter -> 9.55V
Base - Emitter ------> 0.04V
```

Now, my diagram looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu1eXZ.png)</sup>

**Update4 (Working Diagram):**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2yUGu.png)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56226/discussion-on-question-by-vishal-why-is-the-relay-switched-by-a-npn-transistor-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no guarantee Arduino can pull the base that low...

[image]

You either need to add a diode under that transistor and reduce the resistor to closer to 500R so it turns on harder or better, switch to N-Channel MOSFETS.

Comment: If I switch to MOSFETS, then will there be any need for C2 and D2? Also, will I need a PULL-DOWN resistor on the base of Q2?

Comment: D2 is still needed for flyback protection, C2 you can ditch or make small. Pull-down is a good idea for keeping the MOSFET in a known state during power on / CPU reset.

Comment: OK. I will try it and tell you if I was successful.

Comment: @Trevor: Aren't those specs worse-case when sinking 20mA?  Surely that's not the case here.  What is the part number of the relay you're using (link to datasheet?).  Maybe the 2222's are cooked?  What do you _measure_ on DIO9?  On the collector of Q2?  Double-Quadruple check that the transistors are wired properly.  Also, you could remove C2.  Read this: [link](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=13C3311_AppNote&DocType=CS&DocLang=EN)

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen, Yes they are, but there is no minimum, and his base is at 0.13V which is not enough to turn off that transistor. And apparently his high is not supplying enough juice either. YOu need to read the comments in the question. Lots of numbers there.

Comment: Can I use a disk type capacitor instead of electrolytic capacitor? Because I don't have an electrolytic capacitor of value less than 1uF. I have a disk type capacitor which has 103 written on it. I think its value is 10nF according to my calculations. Can I use that? As you say, if I ditch C2 then I think my relay will not switch smoothly am I right?

Comment: @Vishal, yes that will be fine, though you really don't need it in this application.

Comment: I have removed C2 right now. I have different results now. Now, When SW1 and SW2 are LOW the voltage between base and emitter is 0.52 Volts which was 0.13V before removing C2. In this condition if I check the voltage between the arduino output at D9 and GND, I get 0V. Same connection from D9 goes to the base of Q2. There is only one resistor between them. Then why am I getting 0.52 V across base and emitter of Q2?

Comment: @Trevor, I completely overlooked the 'show more comments' link.  My apologies.

Comment: @Vishal  What voltages do you get on the collector when pin D9 is high now?.

Comment: When pin D9 is high, I get the same voltage as before removing capacitor. i.e. 7.51V

Comment: @Vishal,  I still think that transistor is sick... or maybe in backwards.

Comment: @Vishal, take it out, the 2n2222,  then power up your board and use a your multimeter in dc-amps setting to manually connect the collector pad to ground. See if a. the relay switches and opens, and b. what the current is. Also check the voltages while you are at it.

Comment: Can you please check the update part in question. I have noted down all the voltages for you to make sure that if transistor is sick.

Comment: @Trevor Sorry, I felt asleep. It was 4 o'clock in the morning. Can you now please check update2 Part in question?

Comment: @Trevor can you please also check update3 part in question?

Comment: Can I use JFET instead of MOSFET? Because I have a JFET K117. Here is the datasheet: http://www.datasheetspdf.com/PDF/K117/607277/1

Comment: @vishal (I'm just a student) which coding language u used in your question?  (It looks like C coding, curious to know its name)

Comment: @KrishnShweta Its a language like C, which is developed by Arduino. You can learn more about it here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA567CE235D39FA84

Comment: @Vishal, btw I think there is a "bug" in your code. "Counter" will eventually roll over when both switches are high which will cause the first test to pass and that relay to switch. I'm not sure if you intended that or not but. You probably should add an else to the first test too to refresh the relay off if counter <>1. Also I don't see you initializing anything in the setup block.. i.e. relays off. It's probably supposed to initialize that way on power up, but you never know, esp if there are other reset modes that do not clear the register set.

Comment: OK, I will initialize the relays to off in my setup block. Also I will add else block. Now, I have made the circuit from scratch using MOSFETS instead of BJTs. I will update my question with new diagram and problems.

Comment: Please take a look at Update4 part in question.

Comment: @vishay Gate threshold voltage is too high with that mosfet you need one ~2V

Comment: @Trevor Minimum Gate threshold voltage is 2.0V while maximum gate threshold voltage is 4.0V. Here is the datasheet: http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/67488/INTERSIL/IRF614.html Also if you think that I should use another MOSFET, then can you please suggest the name of the MOSFET that I should use?

Comment: @Trevor what if I remove resistors over gate?

Comment: @Vishal.. dude I can't hold your hand till this works... Resistor wont help. MOSFET gate current is extremely low. You need the right part. Experiment a little.

Comment: @Vishal, good luck. I am confident you can figure it out . You just have to think it though step by step :)

Comment: Thanks for help. I got it to work by replacing IRF164 with 2N7000

Answer (score 0):

> B. When D9 is LOW:
>
> Emitter - Ground ------> 0.70V
> Base - Ground ---------> 0.65V

that's your problem: when D9 is low, and emitter is grounded, there is no way you could have observed a voltage differential between the emitter and ground, and there is no way base is 0.65v above ground.

I would suspect faulty connection or faulty transistor.

BTW, no point in adding a diode to the emitter -> makes zero sense.

Comment: I have used N channel Mosfet instead of BJT and it works fine now. I have checked the BJT after removing it. It wasn't faulty at all. In the answer by trevor, he told me that I need a diode under BJT and so I did that. I think I misunderstood the concept that he was trying to explain me. Although my circuit is working fine now, I want to know the meaning of `You need a diode under that transistor`. Can you explain me?